# meaning of $ \{ \alpha \in S_n : \alpha(1) = 1 \} $ in group theory textbook question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

The following is an exercise question from "Guide to Abstract Algebra, 1st ed, Carol Whitehead".

> Decide, giving reasons, whether each of the following subsets of $S_n$
> ($n \geq 2$), is or is not a subgroup:
>
> (a) $ \{ \alpha \in S_n : \alpha(1) = 1 \} $
>
> (b) $ \{ \alpha \in S_n : \alpha(1) = 2 \} $

**Question:** I don't understand the definitions of the subsets.

---

**My thoughts:**

Let's consider $S_3$, which contains permutations which map $[1,2,3]$ to $[1,3,2]$ and $[2, 3, 1]$, for example. These can be represented using cycle notation as $(2\;3)$ and $(1\;2\;3)$.

Let's now consider the subset $H = \{ \alpha \in S_n : \alpha(1) = 1 \} $.

Is this all the permutations which preserve the mapping $1 \mapsto  1$ ?

So $(2\;3) \in H$ because it doesn't affect 1, but $(1\;2\;3) \notin H$ because it maps $1 \mapsto 2$.

Is this a correct understanding of the subsets defined in the exercise?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Note that generally curly brackets denote sets, which do not carry an inherent order of their elements. So when you write "maps $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,3,2\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$", one does not interpret this as saying that it sends $1$ to $1$ and sends $2$ and $3$ to $2$ and $3$, because one interprets $\{1,3,2\}$ as "the set whose elements are $1$, $3$, and $2$", which is *identical* to $\{1,2,3\}$, "the set whose elements are $1$, $2$, and $3$." So you need different notation to convey the idea that you are mapping in order. Common is two-line notation, or cycle notation.

Comment: hi Arturo - I've changed the notation to "list" notation to indicate order is important. Hopefully the cycle notation has helped clarity.

Comment: To make sure people get a notification when you reply to them in a comment, you should use the `@`; so instead of `hi Arturo`, you would use `@ArturoMagidin`. You get a notification of comments on this post without us "pinging" you with an `@` because you are the question's "owner".

Comment: I commented "That is correct" because I knew what you meant, but I agree with Prof. Magidin that technically you should use notation like $(1,2,3)$ rather than $\{1,2,3\}$ to indicate that order matters

Comment: "Is this all the permutations which preserve the mapping $1↦1$?": yes, though I'd rather say "...the permutations which fix $1$".

Comment: @tronk "fix 1" is much clearer. Oddly the textbook introduces that terminology in the prose but didn't use it again.